# Как выполнить задачу на эмуляторах запуская их последовательно одной командой?

Tags: android, gradle

Создал некоторое количество эмуляторов через `Android Studio`. Задача следующая:

1. Запустить первый эмулятор
2. Выполнить автотесты
3. Закрыть эмулятор
4. Повторить пункты 1-3 на необходимом количестве эмуляторов (их может быть и 20)

Для всей задачи при этом использовав одну команду.

Создал сдедующие задачи `gradle`:

```
def sdkDir = ".../Android/sdk/"

task runEmulator1(type: Exec) {
    group = "custom"

    String[] command = [sdkDir + "tools/emulator.exe", '-avd', 'Nexus_5X_Android_8.0'];
    commandLine command
}

task runEmulator2(type: Exec) {
    group = "custom"

    String[] command = [sdkDir + "tools/emulator.exe", '-avd', 'Nexus_S_Android_5.1'];
    commandLine command
}

task closeEmulator(type: Exec) {
    group = "custom"

    def command = ['adb', 'emu', 'kill']
    commandLine command
}
```

И пробую решить задачу командой:

> ./gradlew runEmulator1 connectedCheck closeEmulator runEmulator2
>   connectedCheck closeEmulator

Но после запуска первого эмулятора, первая задача не заканчивается и вторая не начинается. Если использовать начиная с `connectedCheck`, то задачи выполняются корректно (до `runEmulator2`)

Ещё пробовал для запуска следующую задачу:

```
task runEmulator1Process  {
    group = "custom"

    String[] aCommand = [sdkDir + "tools/emulator.exe", '-avd', 'Nexus_5X_Android_8.0'];
    try {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(aCommand).start();
        process.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Но в этом случае эмулятор запускается даже при компиляции проекта.

Как добиться необходимого результата?

Comment: Если с инглишем дружите, почитайте [документацию](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html) . Насколько я понял, один и тот же таск не выполнится дважды.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что у вас проблема кроется в том, что эмулятор не стартует сразу после выполнения `emulator.exe`. Ему надо время на инициализацию и т.п.
Если вы дождетесь его реального старта, то все может получиться.

Инспирацию можете почерпнуть, порывшись в исходниках плагина для Jenkins:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-emulator-plugin

Там у них та же проблема решается: запустить эмулятор, дождаться его и только тогда к след. таску.

**Дополнено**
Прошу прощения, сначала не понял всей сути проблемы.
Похоже, что Gragle всегда ждет завершения внешней команды, асинхронно можно запустить с помощью чего-то такого самописного:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864205/run-javaexec-task-in-background-and-then-terminate-when-build-completes/42557798#42557798

Как более простой вариант, можно попробовать написать для каждого эмулятора свой `.bat`-файл типа

```
start <sdkDir>/tools/emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_Android_8.0
```

И его запускать из Gradle. Суть в том, чтобы `cmd` запускал внешнюю команду и завершался, тогда Gradle-задачи не будут "зависать".

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Gradle задача runEmulator1 дожидается открытия эмулятора, только так и продолжает висеть, не заканчивая свою работу

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: А как этот bat файл выполнить одной командой с остальными задачами gradle?

Comment: как `emulator.exe` выполняете, так и `emulatorX.bat` выполняйте. Можете один `.bat` написать, который можно с параметрами запускать. Т.е. по-сути вам надо обертку над  запуском `emulator.exe` написать для `cmd`

Comment: Понял, интересная идея, но этот способ не подошел, первая задача так же не завершается. Пробую написать асинхронную задачу для моего случая